# Gaming Database Query for multiple players

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a SQL result look like this (match result query):

```
ID    Arena     Winner     Loser     Winner_score   Loser_score
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       Johnny      Mark          16            8
2       2       Andrew      Luke          16            7
```

Here are my tables (simplified)

**Player_tbl**

```
ID    Player     
-------------
1     Johnny
2      Mark  
3     Andrew
4      Luke
```

**Match_tbl**

```
ID    Match     Arena    
----------------------
1     Match 1     1
2     Match 2     2
```

**Match_results_tbl**

```
ID    Match     player_id   player_score
-----------------------------------------
1     Match 1      1            16
2     Match 1      2             8
1     Match 2      3            16
2     Match 2      4             7
```

I am wondering how to structure my query to have the desired result.

Comment: What has your research shown, regarding a possible solution?

Comment: I have no issues with getting a single player result in the single line (like my desired result), but when I have two players, it comes back with two results for a single record. So instead of the results being (match 1, match 2, and the players) it comes back with (match 1, match 1, match 2, match 2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out my own issue. 1st, the match_results must be put in a table with a different structure, and 2nd, the inner sql query needed to be adjusted to pull from the proper database tables.